# Can Ajax be used in GTK WebKitWebView?

Tags: c, ajax, gtk3, webkit2

I am trying to embed an HTML view in my Gtk3 program. In that HTML view, I want to use Ajax. Does this work? How could this be achieved.

I made a few experiments in C with the following code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <webkit2/webkit2.h>

static void activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data){
  GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  WebKitWebView *webView = WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(webkit_web_view_new());
  WebKitSettings *settings = webkit_web_view_get_settings (webView);
  webkit_settings_set_enable_javascript (settings, TRUE);
  webkit_settings_set_allow_file_access_from_file_urls(settings, TRUE);
  webkit_web_view_load_uri(webView, "file:/home/userxy/ajax_gtk_test/test_ajax.html");
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), GTK_WIDGET(webView));
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv){
  GtkApplication *app;
  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
}
```

I am compiling the code with `` gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o example example.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config webkit2gtk-4.0 --cflags --libs` `` .
The HTML page I am loading is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo">
<p>This is an AJAX test.</p>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    this.responseText;
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "file:/home/userxy/ajax_gtk_test/ajax_info.txt");
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The page is loaded. But it is not updated, after clicking the button.

In a web browser, I can open that file, and the Ajax mechanism works as expected.

The same with "in-place" java script works as expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">This is an AJAX test.</p>
<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Ajax works."'>Change Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

So it seams that only the reloading mechanism for external files is disabled in Gtk Webkit2. But I don't find a way to enable this.

Comment: Doesn't AJAX require JQuery library that somehow your client program doesn't find but the browser can sort out?